# mysql - JOIN (table name)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have database with a table called `sites` (which has a few fields, including a `site_ID` field), and a set of tables for each `site_ID` entry from the sites table.

so the db looks something like:

```
- sites [site_ID, blah]
- site_1_articles [title, content]
- site_1_comments [author, comment]
- site_2_articles [title, content]
- site_2_comments [author, comment]
- site_3_articles [title, content]
- site_3_comments [author, comment]
etc...
```

I have a select query which pulls out all the fields from the `sites` table:

```
SELECT * FROM sites
WHERE ....
```

How can I also get the `title` field from the appropriate `site_[site_ID]_articles` table ?
I thinking I need this in the same query using JOIN because the number of tables is quite large (over 1000), and doing 1000 selects is probably not the way to do this :)

Comment: Be more specific, post the actual column and table names you are working with and which column you need

Comment: sorry, I'll rewrite the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot reference tables dynamically (unless using a stored proc to create prepared statements)

You should design your database, to hole a single `site_articles` table, which will store a `site_id` column, then in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sites s JOIN site_articles sa ON s.site_id = sa.site_id
WHERE ....
```

Comment: but wouldn't this make the table very large? One site can have hundreds of articles, and if you have like 2000 sites you get a huge amount of records for one table

Comment: @alex If you index it properly, and use partitioning if needed, it wont be a problem

Answer (score 1):

You can join on multiple conditions, or add it to the WHERE clause

```
...
ON (blah = boo) AND (some_id = matching_field_in_second_table)
...
```

or

```
...
WHERE (some_id = matching_field_in_second_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT blah, some_id, second_table.some_field FROM first_table
LEFT JOIN second_table
ON second_table.some_field = some_id
WHERE ....
```

Is that what you wany?

Answer (score 1):

The best is to redesign your database. a table articles with a id column as primary key and a table comments with an article_id column. Then you join on that.